# How to Install cxf:1.1.1 server in Grails 2.3.0

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-tool-suite

I tried to install the plugin for cxf server in order to expose some grails services as SOAP web services,  according to Grails 2.3 the new plugin installation is:

`compile ":cxf:1.1.1"`

in plugins section of `BuildConfig.groovy`, however it does not work, I tried to expose a service and the annotations are not recognized,  I am working with GGTS (Groovy Grails Tool Suite) and I can't see the plugin installed under the plugin section.

My environment is Grails 2.3, Java 7, Groovy 2.1

Has anybody tried this plugin using Grails 2.3.0 and stumbled upon this issue in GGTS?

Comment: https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf-client-demo/tree/grails-2.3.0 I believe this project might help..See if you are using it similarly.

Comment: Thanks Manisha, I forgot to mention that I was intalling cfx server not client. I edited the post now my problem is other, it shows this error when run-app:  ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the annotations to be recognized you'll need to import the following libraries into the interface or service class you're using to expose the endpoint:

```
import javax.jws.WebService
import org.grails.cxf.utils.EndpointType
import org.grails.cxf.utils.GrailsCxfEndpoint
```

The plugin should show up in the plugins dir if you refresh the dependencies for the project.

Comment: Thanks, it worked however now is sending me when I run the app: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus any Ideas?

Comment: Check under classpath / Grails Dependencies in your project explorer view in GGTS... this should be installed under the cxf-rt-core JAR...

Comment: I don't have that jar under Grails Dependencies, it seems the plugin installs but no libraries, can I add them manually or change something on my BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: I uncommented in buildconfig the maven repositories that are cleary commented and says: " // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories" and it compiled